# t-shirt seller website database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

This is a database I designed for t-shirt seller website, is it ok?
Can it track the quantity of shirt according to size and color of the shirt?
for example: based on this database below, can I know the quantity of the shirt have size XL and are red color? Thank You

[image: t-shirt seller website database]

Comment: School assignment? Have you even created the schema and added sample data? Tried any queries?

Comment: yup it's school assignment, I've just design this diagram, dear : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flaw in the design. A product has variants (size and color) you store in the quantity table. So of one product "Jungle Shirt" you could have for instance:

```
size  color  quantity
M     green  10
L     green  20
M     brown  12
```

But orders can only contain products, not variants. So you could order the "Jungle Shirt", but wouldn't know which size or color you'd get. This is certainly not desired :-)

I'd rename the quantity table to `product_variant` or something along those lines, give it an id (`product_variant_id`) and have `order_detail` contain this id rather than `product_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can know, if table only contains tshirts

```
Select sum(quantity) from quantity where size='XL' and color='red'
```

and if you want to learn which products also you should join with product table